# angular production build not bootstrapping when wrapping angular element

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-components

I have created angular element using `angular 7` and tested standalone with an html file (after including element JS file ) which is working fine.

It is also working fine, when I include Angular element in other `Angular 7` project and running local setup using `ng server`.

Whenever I build the angular project with the `--prod` and try to run the application, the parent application is not bootstrapping.

When I remove the element js reference and custom html and build the application using `--prod`, application `bootstrap/` run perfectly.

I am using angular 7.2 to build both web-component/element and application.

I need help to identify why the application is not running/bootstrapping along with the angular element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While troubleshooting the issue come across the blog :
https://medium.com/swlh/multiple-angular-apps-on-a-single-page-9f49bc863177

I went with option 3 (as already binding element inside angular application) :Ngx Build Plus

the only thing you need to take care is to install appropriate version of build plus, I used ng add ngx-build-plus@7

install the ngx-build in both the project and set different jsonpFunction has resolved the issue.